# Rails - Dynamic Select - Collection Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to get some dynamic select functionality working, but despite many different tutorial i've yet to get it to work. For ease of reading, i've brought the code examples down to basics. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

On the faults page, i need to assign a company and contact to the fault, but I only want to be able to see the contacts associated with the selected company

```
Fault - belongs_to :company, :user, :contact
User - has_many :faults
Contacts - has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
Company - has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts, has_many :faults
```

/faults/_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :company, "Company:" %>

<%= collection_select(:fault,:company_id,@companies,:id,:full_name, :prompt => "Please select a company") %></br>

<%= f.label :contact, "Contact:" %>

<%= f.collection_select :contact_id, @contacts, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a Contact" %>

<%= link_to "Add New Contact", {:controller => "companies", :action => "index"}, :confirm => "To add a contact for a company you need to do this from the companies page." %></br>
```

Comment: And what are the associations in the Company model?  Also, rails 3 or rails 4?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Gotcha.  Using UJS you can dynamically populate your select in 5 steps.

1. Add class names to your selects in the view
2. Add JavaScript (or CoffeeScript) to watch the changes on the select element
3. Create a controller method to fetch the info you need based on your selection
4. Add a route to match your new controller method
5. Create a UJS view to update your contacts select

So,

1. Add class names:

   ```
   <%= f.label :company, "Company:" %>
   <%= collection_select(:fault,:company_id,@companies,:id,:name, {:prompt => "Please select a company"}, {:class => "company_selection"}) %>
   <%= f.label :contact, "Contact:" %>
   <%= f.collection_select :contact_id, @contacts, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select a Contact"}, {:class=>"contact_selection"} %>
   ```
2. Throw in some CoffeeScript (`app/assets/javascripts/faults.js.coffee`)

   ```
   $(document).ready ->
     $(".company_selection").on "change", ->
       $.ajax
         url: "/faults/get_contacts"
         type: "GET"
         dataType: "script"
         data:
           company_id: $('.company_selection option:selected').val()
   ```
3. Update your faults controller

   ```
   def get_contacts
     @company = Company.find params[:company_id]
     @contacts = @company.contacts
   end
   ```
4. Add a route to your new method

   ```
   resources :faults do
     collection do
       get 'get_contacts', to: "faults#get_contacts"
     end 
   end
   ```
5. Add the UJS file (`app/views/faults/get_contacts.js.erb`)

   ```
   $('.contact_selection').empty();
   $('.contact_selection').append( $('<option>Select the Contact</option>'));
   <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
     $('.contact_selection').append($('<option value="<%= contact.id %>"><%= contact.name %></option>'));
   <% end %>
   ```

Comment: Just noticed this, in $('.contact_selection').append($('<option value="<#= contact.id %>"><%= contact.name %></option>')); It says <#= contact.id, which should be <%= contact.id

Comment: How do you test your view with Rspec and Capybara? How do you tell it to wait until the AJAX call is finished can you describe please?

Comment: for the route, you should better ask for a post instead of get... if you call a get, you will also start some automatic mecanisms on Rails and will get some issues.
Also, you can better separate Rails code from javascript code by render a partial: 

``` (coffeescript code)
$("#my_dropdown_to_populate").html ' <%= (j(render partial: "my_view_directory/my_partial_file", locals: {my_data: @the_data_from_controller } ) %>'
```

then create this partial file .html (.erb or .haml if you got it).

Answer (score 1):

#### Vanilla JS Option

This can be achieved with vanilla javascript only. Make sure that there is a route at `companies/[id]/contacts.json` which returns correct data.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#company_id');
select.addEventListener('change',function(e) {
  axios.get(`/companies/${e.target.value}/contacts.json`)
    .then((res) => {
      let contactSelect = document.querySelector('#contact_id')
      contactSelect.innerHTML = ''
      res.data.map((model, i) => {
        contactSelect.options[i] = new Option(model.name, model.id);
      })
    })
});
```