# How to make the collection in a select input dependent on the value of another select input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I'm not even sure where to start here, so if anyone can even just point me in a potential direction that would be helpful.

I have a form in my Rails app with two select inputs.

Here's the independent select

```
<%= collection_select(:pass, :route_id, Route.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Here's the dependent select

```
<%= collection_select(:pass, :afternoon_trip, Trip.all, :id, :departure) %>
```

Right now each Route (from the independent select) has a number of trips associated with it. The Trip (dependent) select shows all trips as options.

I want to only show in the Trip select only the trips that belong to the selected route. Any thoughts on how to do this?

I also want to change the trip options when someone changes their route selection, but this is a secondary issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909394/rails-dynamic-select-collection-select

Comment: This was helpful, but still having issues -- see my reply below if you have any thoughts on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to tackle this one with some ajax. Get the selected option's id, send that to your controller, and render a new menu based on the data the controller sends back. Pseudo code and coffeescript might look like:

```
# javascript
selectMenu = $('menu selectors')
selectMenu.mouseUp ->
  selectedId = // get menu's selected id
  $.ajax "path/to/populate_dependant?selected_id=" + selectedId


# controller
def populate_dependant
  id = params[:selected_id]
  @collection = Model.where(attribute: id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {}
  end
end


# populate_dependant.js.erb
// write javascript to append the following to your form:
<%= f.label :model %>
<%= f.collection_select :model_id, @collection, :id, :attribute_name, :prompt => "Select something" %>
```

Comment: I think I'm getting screwed up in the controller with something...  
    `def get_trips  
    @route = Route.find(params[:route_id])  
    @trips = @route.trips
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
    end`

And when I include this get_trips.js.erb

  `$('.morning-trip-selection').empty();
  $('.morning-trip-selection').append( $('<option>Select the trip</option>'));
  <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
  $('.morning-trip-selection').append($('<option value="<#= trip.id %>"><%= trip.departure_time %></option>'));
<% end %>`

I get the undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass error

Comment: Sounds like @route.trips returns nil, meaning the route you're testing with has no associated trips. Make sure you are filling your variables correctly. You could try to pry in your controller to see what values your `params`, `@route` and `@trips` end up with. https://github.com/pry/pry

Answer (score 0):

The mouseUp event does not work in steel's answer and it is not clear how to reload the page. The following worked for me. Assume the page where the menu is located is the `show` action of the `trips`  controller.

The coffee script is

```
selectMenu = $('#route_select')
  selectMenu.change ->
    selectedID = $('#route_select :selected').text()
    $.ajax "/trips/populate_dependant?selected_id=" + selectedId
```

Change the `populate_dependant` to

```
def populate_dependant
  id = params[:selected_id]
  session[:collection] = Model.where(attribute: id)
  respond_to :js
  render :populate_dependant
end
```

This stores the collection in the session. Then create a new coffee script page in the views for the controller.

```
#app/views/trips/populate_dependent.coffee.erb
 window.location.reload();
```

This reloads the original page.  Then add the following to the `show` action

```
def show
  ...
  @collection = session[:collection]
  ...
end
```

This works very quickly if using turbolinks.