# collection_select selection changes options for secondary collection_select?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When  `user_id` is selected how can `collection_select :challenge_id` only show the challenges for that `user_id` instead of listing all the challenges?

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.order(:name),:id, :full_name, include_blank: true %>w
  will
<%= f.collection_select :challenge_id, Challenge.order(:deadline),:id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true %>.
```

### UPDATE

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.order(:name),:id, :full_name, include_blank: true, id: "id_of_the_user_id_select_box" %>w
  will
<%= f.collection_select :challenge_id, Challenge.order(:deadline),:id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true %>.

<script>
  $( "#id_of_the_user_id_select_box" ).change(function() {
       $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '<%= user_challenges_path %>',
          data: {name: $('#id_of_the_user_id_select_box').prop('value')}
       });
  });
</script>
```

**challenges_controller**

```
def user_challenges
  # Not sure what to add in here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger an ajax request while selecting `user_id`. Like:

```
$( "#id_of_the_user_id_select_box" ).change(function() {
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '<%= fetch_chanllenges_of_user_path %>', # replace by your route
        data: {name: $('#id_of_the_user_id_select_box').prop('value')}
     });
});
```

Create a new route on your `routes.rb` file with type GET. In the method, you got the `user_id`. Now find the respective challenges of that user. Then replace the second dropdown using a partial.

**EDIT**

create new partial file called `_user_challenges.html.erb` and paste the following code on that file

```
<div id="dropdown-no-2">
   <%= collection_select 'challenge_id', challenges,:id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true %>.
</div>
```

In your view file instead of using the second dropdown use this newly created partial like:

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.order(:name),:id, :full_name, include_blank: true, id: "id_of_the_user_id_select_box" %>w
  will
# below code will be replaced
<%= f.collection_select :challenge_id, Challenge.order(:deadline),:id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true %>.
#  by
<%= render :partial => 'user_challenges', locals: {challenges: Challenge.order(:deadline)} %>
# If you are using an intelligent IDE then the file path of user_challenges.html.erb file will be given as suggestion
```

In the controller:

```
def user_challenges
  # fetch challenges for a specific user
  # I assumed that you've a one to many association between user and challenge
  @user = User.find(params[:name])
  @challenges = @user.challenges.order(:deadline)
end
```

Now for the controller's `user_challenges` method, create a view file named `user_challenges.js.erb`. On that file write the following:

```
$("#dropdown-no-2").html('<%=j render :partial => "user_challenges", locals: {challenges: @challenges} %>');
```

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909394/rails-dynamic-select-collection-select#answer-19914983) also.

Comment: Thank you! Okay I'm stuck on what to do with `routes.rb`. I tried `$ rake routes` `user_challenges GET    /users/:user_id/challenges(.:format)          challenges#index` but I can't get rid of error `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"challenges"} missing required keys: [:user_id]`

Comment: add `get 'challenges/user_challenges', :to => 'challenges#user_challenges'` in the routes file. Now add a method named `user_challenges` in the `ChallengesController`. Find this route using `grep` then add it to ajax url

Comment: Thank you! That did away with the error.  I set the route via `get 'challenges/user_challenges', :to => 'challenges#user_challenges', as: 'user_challenges'`, but upon selecting the user all the challenges still show instead of only the challenges for that user.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, Answer updated. If you still find it difficult, then mate you have to do this on your own with a lots of research. :)