# Why show undefined on rails select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a ajax select on a rails app that is showing undefined on select as shown below,

[image]

I added the `order` scope to fix, but if I remove the `order` list do not show up, and if i put `created_at` or by `name asc`, it shows `undefined`

someone know why?

the on controller is:

```
 def index
   genders = Gender.where(block_id: params[:block_id]).select('id, gender').order('created_at asc')
   render json: genders
 end
```

in the view is:

```
<%=dynamic_collection_select :product, :gender_id, :category, [], :id, :gender, { include_blank: false, submit_with_form: true, :prompt=> 'Select' }, { class: 'form-control select_item' } %>
```

gender object

```
class Gender < ActiveRecord::Base 

  has_many :categories
  belongs_to :block

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories

  attr_accessible :gender,  :categories_attributes

end
```

Comment: @lobbey have updated my answer hope it helps goodluck

Answer (score 1):

You are having `activerecord` collection object, need to convert to JSON,

```
def index
  genders = Gender.where(block_id: params[:block_id]).select('id, gender').order('created_at asc')
  render json: genders.as_json
end
```

Comment: Md. Farhan Memon thank you for your answer but still the same.

Comment: can you post your `genders` object?

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909394/rails-dynamic-select-collection-select), it might help

Comment: Md. Farhan Memon thank you, the select is working just this issue that's happening and i don't have any idea why

Comment: *i changed the order to fix but if i remove the order did not show, and if i put create_at or by name asc show this undefined* this is unclear, please elaborate

Comment: .order('created_at asc')

Comment: i changed the name to created_at

Comment: without the order the list did not appear

Comment: the list appears if you add `.order('created_at asc')`? and it doesn't appear without it? ordering shouldn't change the behaviour...

Comment: exactly! and that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

ensure that you are using an instance variable so that it is visible in the views: @genders, secondly ensure that you are calling that object in your views: e.g. dynamic_collection_select @genders..... etc.

**Summary:**

1. put an @ symbol in front of your variable: @genders
2. call that variable in the collection_select helper method. @genders

**edit**

also why are you rendering as json? shouldn't use render to a html.erb template if you are using jquery?

Comment: hello BKSpurgeon sorry, i did not understood your answer, you mean make gender a global variable @@genders?

Comment: BKSpurgeon is rendering as json becausse is more fast for long lists.

well yes i'm using jquery but json is better for rendering

Comment: can you paste the webrick output as well?>