# Rails & Javascript check which radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is the code of my view (in a form_for)

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
   <%= f.label :Competition_type %> <br>
   <%= f.radio_button :type_competition, :value => "regression", :checked => true, id: "type_regression" %>
   <%= f.label :type_competition, "Regression"%>
   <%= f.radio_button :type_competition, :value => "classification", id: "type_classification" %>
   <%= f.label :type_competition, "Classification"%>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
   <%= f.label :Performance_metric %>
   <%= f.select(:metric, options_for_select([['Mean Absolute Error'],['Root Mean Squared Error'],['Weighted Mean Absolute Error'], ['Accuracy'],['Mean Utility']]), {}, {class: "form-control", id: "selectMetric"}) %>
</div>
```

Somebody helps me to do a function in JavaScript (and/or JQuery) so that when the radio button "regression" is selected, the select options show only ['Mean Absolute Error'],['Root Mean Squared Error'],['Weighted Mean Absolute Error'], and when the radio button "classification" is selected show only the others options: ['Accuracy'],['Mean Utility'].

I will thank you very much. I don't know to do this and I need that to continue my final project of the university.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example uses jquery. write a change listener for radio button check the value and show/hide the options.

**Note: this method won't work in safari/IE. solution is to disable instead hide/show.Let me know if you are a safari user. i will modify my answer **

```js
$("input").change(function(e){
$("select").val('');
  if(e.target.value == "regression"){
     $(".regression").show();
     $(".classification").hide()
    }else{
     $(".classification").show()
     $(".regression").hide();
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value ="regression" name="radio_btn">regression
  <br>
   <input type="radio" value="classification" name="radio_btn">classification
   <br>
   
<select>
<option class="regression">Mean Absolute Error</option><option class="regression">Root Mean Squared Error</option><option class="regression">Weighted Mean Absolute Error</option><option class="classification">Accuracy</option><option class="classification">Mean Utility</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. No, i'm not a safari user. And, the last code....do you know to pass this to ruby (not in HTML)

Comment: Make sure to same id or class in your ruby code as my code has. Js code will be same. Just include this code in your html.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in javascript using

```
if ($('#type_regression').checked){
 // your radio button is checked
}
```

now if you want to fetch data from server
use ajax get function

```
$.get(function(){
url:
successs:

});
```

else you can locally define 2 arrays for both and show them inside if block
and don't pre-define your option_for_select .. rather update them inside javascript if block

you can also refer to this -- >

[Rails - Dynamic Select - Collection Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909394/rails-dynamic-select-collection-select)

Comment: And how would this last option be with the arrays?
How do I do it on select?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus   this is the ans of all your q.